# Automatic translation from Arabic to English in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

Is it possible to create content let's say a website page in Arabic and then have SharePoint translate it into English automatically?
What I want is to have two versions of the website, one Arabic and one English. But don't want to create pages for both sites manually. Just want to create pages in Arabic and SharePoint should translate it into English.

Thanks

Comment: As someone who has worked as a professional translator: Even if there are tools that claim to translate, a machine will never be as good as a skilled translator. If you want your site to be easily understood by the audiences in both languages and cultural settings, then, by all means, let the machine do a first draft, but let a professional translator do the final edit. Have the modicum of respect for your audience and take every possible step not to insult them with bad translations.

Comment: @teylyn, well said, I agree with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can create two same web templates in different languages, as web languages are set on web application level and I also **think** what you want isn't possible in earlier version of SharePoint except SharePoint 2013.

However there is something new in SharePoint 2013 known as [Machine Translation Services in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj163145.aspx) which can be used to get translations directly from Microsoft, but I am not sure about the possible ways to use it the way you want to do.

> Learn about the Machine Translation Service, which is a new service
>   application in SharePoint 2013 that provides automatic machine
>   translation of files and sites.
>
> Applies to:  SharePoint Server 2013

However I would recommend creating different web applications with different languages where applicable and in future custom code you can use resources, which will make your life way easier.

**Edited on 07 03 2013**

I came across another feature named as "[Variation Feature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628966.aspx)" of SharePoint which can be of your interest.

> The variations feature in SharePoint Server 2013 and SharePoint Online
>   makes content available to specific audiences on different sites by
>   syncing content from a source variation site to each target variation
>   site. When users visit the root site, they are redirected to the
>   appropriate variation site, based on the language setting of their web
>   browser. Content on a target variation site can be translated into
>   other languages before it is published. Variations can be used only on
>   sites that are created by using one of the Publishing site templates,
>   or on sites for which the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure
>   feature was activated.

Edit: Mark I haven't been on here long enough to make comments, but I wanted to note a few things.  I believe Variations must be setup in order to use the Machine Translation service.  Also languages can be set per site/sub-site (based on the available languages).  The UI can language can be changed under site settings.

Comment: So basically this Machine Translation Service require that the server is connected to internet so it can get translation from Microsoft? Or it will also work on LAN?

Comment: @FrankMartin Article says, this service supports both asynchronously and synchronously translation, so I guess it will work on LAN too, but that's my thoughts after going through article, don't take it as 100% yes :)