# About SharePoint 2013 display language

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Our sharepoint site has two languages, the default language is English, the other is Chinese.

What is the mechanism for how SharePoint chooses display language in SharePoint 2013?

I have found that it is not only depending on IE attribute.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint to have a site or web in two languages means you need to create two web applications supplying different languages you require. In your case there must be two web applications one created using "English" as language and another created using "Chinese".

However there is something new ["Translation Services"](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/whats-new-public-facing-websites-sharepoint-2013/) in SharePoint 2013 that can be utilized for translation without need of having two web applications.

For more clarity on topic, check out my this answer

[Automatic translation from Arabic to English in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60911/automatic-translation-from-arabic-to-english-in-sharepoint-2013)

**Edit**

> In SharePoint 2013, the language selection (MUI) is a bit different
>   than in 2010.
>
> Your default language settings in your browser of choice will be used
>   by default (same as 2010 btw). So if you have IE set to English as
>   preferred languages, SharePoint will show you the UI in English once
>   you enable it as alternate language.
>
> Now, the big difference is that the dropdown menu for site language
>   selection is gone. Instead, in you MySite, if you go under “About me”,
>   you see a few option in the navbar, click on the “…” to reveal a
>   “Language preferences” menu. From there you can define the language
>   selection associated with your profile on that server.

[Source](http://microsoftechies.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/multilingual-sites-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: I select alternate language:Chinese in the Site Administration--Language settings, but I'm not sure the display language while the users visit the site. I just find that it is not depending on IE language attribute. I want to know what's configuration will impact the display language.

Comment: @user15395 I updated my answer

Comment: currently, the prefer language is setted by using English in IE, also the site's defalut display language is English, but I sitll see a Chinese website, so I'm confusing that are there any other configuration will impact the display language?

Comment: did you tried clearing browser's cookies and also check if you face same issue on any other browser.

Comment: you have to create 2 web applications one for each language?  Is that new in SP 2013??? In sp 2010, you can create resource files and deploy them, then you can use the $resource token in your code or content type xml, or field xml to translate everything.  Creating 2 web apps for only translation makes no sense.

Comment: @LuisValenciaMunoz When you use $resource, it uses culture of web application, so you need to create two web applications with different languages, so that $resource will know which one to pick up... I would recommend you to do some reading...

Comment: in sp 2010 you enable MUI, and then in the upper right corner you can select the language.  when the user changes the language they will see everything translated, and that comes from resource files, You dont need to create 2 web applications for that.  Again, you didnt answer me if thats only for SP 2013.  But for 2010, what you said I havent ever seen it that way as a good practice, show me a link and I will believe it.

Comment: @LuisValenciaMunoz read the limitations of MUI http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805062(v=office.14).aspx#Section7 , and our SharePoint with more then 2000+ users have different web applications for different languages because of complexity, I won't going to answer any more comments, you can talk to me in chat if you want to discuss further.

Comment: I logged into the chat but it doesnt look like a real time chat app, all messages are old.  Lets chat, I need to ask a few things please

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/8470/discuss-mui-in-sp-2013?tab=general

Comment: what about lists? lets say you create a list,  normally you want list items available, having 2 web applications then you need to manage the list in 2 places, sync them someway I guess

Comment: You don't need web Applications. You can use Site collections instead using $resource and changing the Culture.

Comment: yes it is possible but not recommended at all.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism for this is the 'Variations feature' which is exclusively for multi-lingual sites in SharePoint 2013. It gives allows you to have multiple 'variations' of SharePoint languages.
It detects the users browser language setting and displays the site with the matched language.

To enable two or more languages in SharePoint, language packs need to be installed by a SharePoint Administrator.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2011/11/14/sharepoint-variations-the-complete-guide-part-1-the-basics.aspx

ANOTHER new Service Application in SharePoint 2013 is the Machine Translation Service. 
The MTS can translate content to another language in SharePoint.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2012/11/12/introduction-to-machine-translation-services-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Key difference between the 'Variations Feature' and the 'Machine Translation Service' is variations only display SharePoint buttons, labels, menus in SharePoint and not content. Machine Translation Service has the capability of translating content in pages, docx files etc.

Comment: +1 for introducing variations, I am not an expert in SP 2013, but I dont think that you have to create 2 web apps as Muhammad said in previous answer.  Resources can translate controls, and variations are for translating content